# Setting A Layout For All Controllers Actions - CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a controller which needs a layout for all it's actions which will then add their respective views, the layout needs to be different to the default layout of the other controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the **layout** property of the your controller:

```
var $layout = 'new_layout';
```